# List of Lua derived VMs and Languages

Tags: lua, programming-languages, virtual-machine, language-design, language-features

Is there a compendium of virtual machines and languages derived or inspired by Lua?  By derived, I mean usage beyond embedding and extending with modules.  I'm wanting to research the Lua technology tree, and am looking for our combined knowledge of what already exists.

Current List:

- Bright - A C-like Lua Derivative http://bluedino.net/luapix/Bright.pdf
- Agena - An Algol68/SQL like Lua Derivative http://agena.sourceforge.net/
- LuaJIT - A (very impressive) JIT for Lua http://luajit.org
- MetaLua - An ML-style language extension http://metalua.luaforge.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Squirrel](http://squirrel-lang.org/)  -- high level imperative/OO programming language
- [GSL Shell](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/index.html) -- interactive CLI with easy access to the GNU Scientific Library (GSL)
- [Objective Lua](http://olua.sourceforge.net/)  -- almost pure superset of Lua that welds the Objective C object orientation system and syntax on top of the classic Lua language
- [Jill](http://jillcode.googlecode.com/) -- Java Implementation of Lua Language
- [Dao](http://daoscript.org/) -- OO programming language with soft (or optional) typing, BNF-like macro system
- [MoonScript](http://moonscript.org/) -- CoffeeScript inspired language that compiles into lua

Answer (score 9):

There's a good list of Lua implementations on the [lua users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations), including compilers/interpreters, languages implemented in lua and languages based on lua.

[Luaforge](http://luaforge.net/) might also be a good resource.

Comment: Very embarrassed that I missed that page!  However, the question has uncovered some more links that I'll do my best to add to this page.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an implementation, not a list, but there's [Lua-ML](http://www.cminusminus.org/code.html#luaml).  There's an [application paper](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/maniaws-abstract.html) and a [technology paper](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/embedj-abstract.html).
The code is a little out of date; apparently the nightly build at http://www.cminusminus.org/ is broken.